Pressing CTRL+S will execute a macro on a sheet
I just want a simple conditional code where if a user press the shortcut Ctrl+S this will execute
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Thank you
I only know this code but i dont know what else to use to execute my goal
Simple Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit code

Use Workbook_BeforeSave event.
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub


